# Automated video conversion like YouTube

Tags: video, youtube

So obviously YouTube doesn't have gazillion video editors sitting in the office 24/7 and convert videos as they get uploaded... How do they do it?

Above question is edited as below:

In general, they have some sort of converter software installed on the server and it gets called by server-side script to the run conversion.. How does the connection between the software and server-side script made? Which softwares and server side languages are used for this task?

Thank you for your answer/suggestion/comments!

Comment: Voting to close because the question is open ended, and could take an entire book to describe.  Plus you didn't ask anything specifically about programming, and this is a programming site.

Comment: This does involve server-side programming though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Google (Youtube) [are/were using](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/googles-youtube-uses-ffmpeg/) FFMpeg to transcode the videos uploaded by their users

Comment: Looks like php has an extension for this tool... Though I couldn't find anything on using php to request conversion from ffmpeg...

Comment: The linked article is definitely fun reading. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Google bought On2 in 2010 (http://www.on2.com/). The On2 system had good reviews compared with FFMPEG which can be buggy. I think Google just bought them out so others can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

They will have a server-side script or application that detects the file type and runs a converter script/application to convert it to whatever file type they use. In reality, this will probably be queued, rather than be run straight away, as that will lighten the load on the YouTube servers.

Comment: It wouldn't lighten the load, because all videos would eventually have to be processed. It could just distribute it throughout the day. It would also reduce responsiveness/turn-around time of video uploads. When you upload your videos, do they show up instantly?

Comment: It would lighten the load because it means there would be fewer videos being converted at any one time. Sure, it would take longer, but it would have a lower average load on the processor. To answer your question, they sometimes take a a few minutes to appear on your My Videos page. They can take from a few minutes to a few hours to actually process. Near the end of the processing, you can view the video while it is still being processed. I assume this process involves optimising the video and creating the 240p and 360p (and 480p if applicable) versions of the video.

Comment: I would think they'd have "converter" servers that have different work loads.. They'd convert and move the files...

Answer (score 1):

> How do they do it?

Software running on a server.

You could automate video conversion using tools like VirtualDub with saved settings and driving it via the command line.  But I'm sure their specific solution is proprietary (at least the end to end solution would be, even if they've commented on individual pieces publically).